# Retrieve data as nested documents in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Following is a sample set of data that I have in a mongodb collection.

```
{year : 2010 , studentName: "John", grades :{science: 70, maths: 80, english: 85 }}
{year : 2010 , studentName: "Denver", grades :{science: 75, maths: 85, english: 85 }}
{year : 2010 , studentName: "Harry", grades :{science: 85, maths: 75, english: 65 }}
{year : 2011 , studentName: "John", grades :{science: 70, maths: 80, english: 85 }}
{year : 2011 , studentName: "Denver", grades :{science: 75, maths: 85, english: 85 }}
{year : 2011 , studentName: "Harry", grades :{science: 85, maths: 75, english: 65 }}
```

I want to retrieve data with a nested document as the schema below.

```
[{
  "year": 2010,
  "studentGrades": [
    {
      "studentName": "John",
      "grades": {
        "science": 70,
        "maths": 80,
        "english": 85
      }
    },
    {
      "studentName": "Denver",
      "grades": {
        "science": 75,
        "maths": 85,
        "english": 85
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "year": 2011,
  "studentGrades": [
    {
      "studentName": "John",
      "grades": {
        "science": 70,
        "maths": 80,
        "english": 85
      }
    },
    {
      "studentName": "Denver",
      "grades": {
        "science": 75,
        "maths": 85,
        "english": 85
      }
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Can you please help me to write the mongodb query command to get the data between a date range e.g. `year` between `2009 -2011` with results in the above format?

Comment: This looks like a simple [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework with your pipeline having three operators. The first **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** step actes as a filter to only allow documents into the pipeline that satisify a given criteria. This operator is similar to the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method as it uses standard MongoDB queries. For each input document, outputs either one document (a match) or zero documents (no match). This is where you specify the query to look for data between a date range. e.g. Year btween `2009 -2011` inclusive. In that case you would use the **[`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte)** with **[`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/#op._S_lte)** operators to create the range query (for an inclusive range) and **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt)** with **[`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/#op._S_lt)** operators for an exclusive range query.

The second **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step will group the documents in the collection by the `year` field, this key becomes your group `_id`. The `studentGrades` array is then populated by the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** operator which takes in a document expression.

The final **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline reshapes the documents' fields by replacing the `_id` jey with the `year` field and the other field remains the same.

So as a result, you are looking for the following aggregation operation:

```
db.students.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "year": { "$gte": 2009, "$lte": 2011 } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$year",
            "studentGrades": {
                "$push": {
                    "studentName": "$studentName",
                    "grades": "$grades"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": { "_id": 0, "year": "$_id", "studentGrades": 1 }
    }
])
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. How can I query data for a specific year range. e.g. 2008 to 2011 in above example.

Comment: @nzhmz Asking additional questions in the comments not originally in the question is portrayed as a bad habit here on SO since it is very misleading to people who come along and see that answers provided do not match what you have asked. The general case here is one question one answer. If you can edit your question I will be as will others happy to edit my answer to provide the supplimentary requirement.

Comment: valid point. edited the original post with additional question.